# Class deserialization - Differences between Jython and Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, jython

I was able to serialize a custom JFrame into a database, and I would like to deserialize it. 
Unfortunately, during the alleged deserialization I have an error that I cannot resolve.

```
import sys

from java.io import *
from java.lang import Class
from java.sql import *
from methods import *


class MyFrame(JFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        self._title = 'Frame di prova'
        self.setTitle(self._title)
        c = self.getContentPane()

        self._insertN = JTextField(20)
        nameLabelPane, nameFieldPane = incidentPanels(
            JLabel("Nome"), [self._insertN])

        firstBlock = (nameLabelPane, nameFieldPane)

        firstPane = gridPane(firstBlock)

        if self._title.startswith('Modifica'):
            saveBtn = JButton('Modifica')
        else:
            saveBtn = JButton('Salva')

        globalPane = JPanel()
        gridBagger(globalPane, (firstPane, saveBtn))
        c.add(JScrollPane(globalPane))

        self.pack()


SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists serialized_java_objects (object_name varchar(1000), serialized_object blob)"
SQL_SERIALIZE_OBJECT = "INSERT INTO serialized_java_objects(object_name, serialized_object) VALUES (?, ?)"
SQL_DESERIALIZE_OBJECT = "SELECT serialized_object FROM serialized_java_objects limit 1"


def createTable(connection):
    connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(SQL_CREATE_TABLE)

def serializeJavaObjectToDB(connection, objectToSerialize):
    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SERIALIZE_OBJECT)

    pstmt.setString(1, 'Frame di prova')
    pstmt.setObject(2, objectToSerialize)
    pstmt.executeUpdate()
    pstmt.close()

def deSerializeJavaObjectFromDB(connection):
    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_DESERIALIZE_OBJECT)
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery()
    rs.next()

    buf = rs.getBytes(1)
    objectIn = None
    if (buf != None):
        objectIn = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(buf))

    deSerializedObject = objectIn.readObject()

    rs.close()
    pstmt.close()

    return deSerializedObject


def getMySqlConnection():
    mysqlConn = None

    mysqlLog_server = "localhost"
    mysqlLog_username = "root"
    mysqlLog_password = ""
    mysqlLog_database = "tuttle"

    properties = Properties()
    properties.put("user", mysqlLog_username)
    properties.put("password", mysqlLog_password)

    url = "jdbc:mysql://" + mysqlLog_server + "/" + mysqlLog_database + \
        "?user=" + mysqlLog_username + "&password=" + mysqlLog_password

    mysqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
    return mysqlConn


def main(args):
    frame = MyFrame()
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    connection = getMySqlConnection()
    createTable(connection)

    serializeJavaObjectToDB(connection, frame)
    objFromDatabase = deSerializeJavaObjectFromDB(connection)

    objFromDatabase.setVisible(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

The error is at the line `objFromDatabase = deSerializeJavaObjectFromDB(connection)`, In particular on `deSerializedObject = objectIn.readObject()` and it's the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "provaSerializzazione.py", line 119, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "provaSerializzazione.py", line 113, in main
    objFromDatabase = deSerializeJavaObjectFromDB(connection)
  File "provaSerializzazione.py", line 74, in deSerializeJavaObjectFromDB
    deSerializedObject = objectIn.readObject()
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.python.proxies.__main__$MyFrame$3
```

Curious the fact that, if you replace the line `frame = MyFrame()` with `frame = JFrame()` the function serializes correctly, without errors. 
It almost seems like the deserializing function doesn't accept a python class (which in turn extends a JFrame).
What should I do to deserialize my `MyFrame` class in the jython language? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't seem like a deserialization problem. Looks like your MyFrame class doesn't exist at the classpath.

Comment: @OnurBaştürk So what would you suggest me to do?

Comment: Well I don't use Python. Therefore I don't know how you import java objects into a python project. May be you can explain the structure of your project and the import mechanism then i'd try to find a way. Let me ask first. Is MyFrame a Java object? I think it's not

Comment: You say that you can serialize a custom JFrame object into the database. I think that custom object is MyFrame right? And what does the data look like in the database? Is it in JSON format or sth. else?

Comment: The data type in the database is `BLOB`, since it is a serialized object. It is saved, and I am quite proud of that. The error occurs at the time of deserialization. `class MyFrame(JFrame)` is a Python/Jython class that extends Java's `JFrame` class, and this probably does not appeal to the (Java) deserializer. In fact, if I declared a JFrame eg with `f = JFrame()`, on the whole program execution there would be no problems! But I need the extension of the class...

Comment: Yeah I see that. May be you could insert the data in JSON format and then convert it to your MyFrame object after selecting it as a string. I think there will be some library in Jython to do the JSON deserialization. There is Jackson library in Java, and i see that there is a python-javaobj library. I think this approach will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `org.python.util.PythonObjectInputStream` instead of `java.io.ObjectInputStream`.